# Is there any way to check chroma sampling applied (MacBook Air M2)?

Tags: hdmi

My monitor does not show anything but the resolution information. Is there any way to check if my computer runs 4:4:4 instead of any other mode.

My laptop is connected to my screen Type C to HDMI 2.1.

Graphics/Displays:

```
Apple M2:

  Chipset Model: Apple M2
  Type: GPU
  Bus: Built-In
  Total Number of Cores: 8
  Vendor: Apple (0x106b)
  Metal Support: Metal 3
  Displays:
    M28U:
      Resolution: 3840 x 2160 (2160p/4K UHD 1 - Ultra High Definition)
      UI Looks like: 1920 x 1080 @ 120.00Hz
      Main Display: Yes
      Mirror: Off
      Online: Yes
      Rotation: Supported
```